# type mismatch error in vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

i have a code by running individually(using F8 key) i can get output. whereas if i run using F5 it shows TYPE MISMATCH ERROR. how to fix it.
 program for your reference:

```
Sub Getting_BOM()
     Sheets("DATA").Range("a6:F1000").ClearContents

    'Launching Web Page
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    URL = "http://home.gsi.local/VBGSIWeb/Production/PackingList.aspx"

    ie.Navigate2 URL
    Do While ie.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
    Loop

    Do While ie.Busy = True
    DoEvents
    Loop

    pnumber = Sheets("DATA").Range("B2").Value

    Sheets("DATA").Select

    If pnumber <> "" Then
        Do While ie.Busy = True
        DoEvents
        Loop

        Set search_box = ie.document.getelementbyid("txtItem")
        search_box.Value = pnumber

        Do While ie.Busy = True
        DoEvents
        Loop

        If search_box Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Connect GSI Cisco first !!!", vbCritical, "GSI Cisco Problem"
            Shell "C:\Program Files\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnui.exe", vbNormalFocus
            ie.Quit
            Sheets("DATA").Select
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Set table_val = ie.document.getelementbyid("lblPackListDescription")
        Do While ie.Busy = True
        DoEvents
        Loop

        Set search_Button = ie.document.getelementbyid("btnSearch")
        search_Button.Click

        '    IE.Visible = True
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))

        Set Table_header = ie.document.getelementbyid("lblPackListDescription")

        If errno > 5 Then
            Sheets("DATA").Range("d6").Value = "Invalid Item Number"
            errno = 0
            Err.Clear
            GoTo Here
        End If

        If Table_header.innertext = 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            GoTo Here
        End If

        If Err Then
            errno = errno + 1
            Err.Clear
            GoTo there
        End If
there:
        n = 5
        For i = 6 To 300
            **Set table_val = ie.document.getelementbyid("dgPacklist")**(here it shows as error)
            availability = 0
            nn = (i - 5)
            components = table_val.Cells(nn * (11 + availavlity)).innertext

            If components = " " Then Exit For

            n = n + 1
            Range("B" & n).Select
            Sheets("DATA").Range("a" & n).Value = (i - 5)

            Description_val = table_val.Cells((nn * (11 + availability)) + 1).innertext
            qty_val = table_val.Cells((nn * (11 + availability)) + 2).innertext

            Sheets("DATA").Range("B" & n).Value = Mid(components, 1, 500)
            Sheets("DATA").Range("C" & n).Value = qty_val
        Next i

    End If
    Call Module1.Part_Long_Description
    Call Module1.Paste_Description
    'Call Module1.SaveAs_CSV
    MsgBox "Task Finished", vbInformation, "Finished"
Here:
    ie.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't tell me, we have to guess which line errors?

Comment: Well, the first question, since you declare NONE of your variables, is what is the data type of `ie.document.getelementbyid("dgPacklist")`?  If it is not an object, then you should not be using the `Set` statement

Comment: @SJR It's embedded in the code.

Comment: Actually, it is a table in the above said url and i have to extract the data from it.

Comment: (Almost) anything that works with F8, but not with F5 is likely to be falling over itself, starting on a new line of code before the last one has completed. Especially evident where calls to other programs are concerned.

Comment: how can we define "dgPacklist" as it is in the table format

Comment: You can't get the table contents of an html by setting an object to it's ID. @Ron Rosenfeld is correct.  Try looking at these webpage instructions,  https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/700058-visual-basic-applications-code-extract-html-table-data-worksheet.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205442/excel-vba-get-inner-text-of-html-table-td, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700115/vba-to-extract-html-table-data

Comment: Just Guessing, When You use F8 you give sufficient time to AJAX and javascript to load , But when you use F5 page may not be fully loaded. I will suggest you to apply , Application.wait for 3-5 seconds before the line which throws error.